# make sure Code is only using features available in Android minSdkVersion with maven and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock

We have an Android app that is using ActionBarSherlock and has the following Manifest configuration:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Lately we encountered crashes because we hat the following code line in the app:

```
String type = ... 
if (type.isEmpty()) {
   ...
}
```

because the ***isEmpty()*** method is not available in **Android 2.2.x** (out **minSdkVersion 8** we still support).

So we want to find that problem in development, while compiling the app an not when running on the device. Configuring Android version 2.2.x as SDK by setting

```
<sdk>
  <platform>8</platform>
</sdk>
```

in the **maven** build configuration leads to the problem that the build fails because of ActionBarSherlock:

```
[INFO] ../target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_library_apklib_4.1.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:4: error: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
```

So my question: Is there a way to compile with the **correct SDK** that makes sure everything in the code is compatible with the devices specified in **minSdkVersion AND use ActionBarSherlock?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ActionBarSherlock you have to compile with a later SDK. But you can use [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) to check for these [invalid API calls](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) at build time.

Comment: I feared so, will try to add that lint checks to the maven build ant let it fail